# Swagger 2.0 - attribute responses.responses.bad$ref is not of type `object`

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger 2.0.
Facing the error  on UI as:

> {"messages":["attribute responses.responses.bad$ref is not of type `object`"],"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","domain":"validation","keyword":"oneOf","message":"instance failed to match exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 2)","schema":{"loadingURI":"http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#","pointer":"/definitions/parameter"},"instance":{"pointer":"/parameters/bad$ref"}}]}

It's a YAML based documentation with the following file referencing in the main `swagger.yaml`.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  $ref: ./info/index.yaml
host: example.net
basePath: /api/v1
tags:
  - name: Name
    description: description
schemes:
  - http
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
consumes:
  - application/json
parameters:
  $ref: ./parameters/index.yaml
responses:
  $ref: ./responses/index.yaml
paths:
  $ref: ./paths/index.yaml
definitions:
  $ref: ./definitions/index.yaml
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: 'http://swagger.io'
```

Folder structure:

[image]

The `parameters/index.yaml` and `responses/index.xml` files are empty. This works perfectly in the Swagger Editor.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete `swagger.yaml` file and also `parameters/index.yaml` and `responses/index.yaml`?

Comment: Added swagger.yaml
Both parameter/index.yaml and responses/index.yaml are completely empty